# Trying to set up virtual MIDI throughput to use a single MIDI device with multiple Applications

Tags: midi, controller

**Motivation**
*I occasionally stream with OBS and have my own virtual audio mixer (Voicemeeter Potato),*
Since I had multiple Drumpads collecting dust I figured in stead of buying an Elgato StreamDeck for €150,- I would try to find some freeware to convert MIDI information to keystrokes so I can switch my OBS scenes with my Akai MPD218.
Then I decided I would want to use the device for voicemeeter as well since it has a bunch of knobs I could use to adjust volumes of different sources independently.

**Relevant System Information**

> - Akai MPD218
> - Windows 10 Home x64
> - loopMIDI
> - MIDIKey2Key
> - Voicemeeter Potato
> - OBS

**Issue**
*I soon found out that apparently, you can't use one MIDI device on multiple applications at the same time.* I now am faced with the problem where I'm unable to throughput my `ContinuousController` signal to a new virtual MIDI device correctly. I can make it increment by a set amount but when I turn the knob to the other side in stead of decreasing, it would still increase by the same amount.

What I would love to know is how I can set different outputs depending on the direction of the knob or if that's even possible since the MIDI information that it inputs is just absolute data values.
would I have to set a separate action for all the 127 different volume levels?

**Notes/Edits**
*Voicemeeter is not receiving the MIDI information directly from the device,* it would receive the virtual "translated" MIDI information from MIDIKey2Key sending 'actions' through the virtual MIDI port I set up with loopMIDI

Another application (alternatives) that would be able to send/throughput/separate the different MIDI channels would also be useful.
I know my controller knobs are using a different midi channel from my physical pads. Being able to separate these and split/send them to different applications (over virtual midi devices?) would solve my issue.